# Sharepoint product configuration failed!

Tags: configuration-wizard

I installed  sharePoint 2013 successfully. But after everything being installed for no reason I changed my servername! After that nothing seems to work properly.

So I renamed it back but When I reran the Sharepoint product configuration, it failed with this message:

An exception of type System.IO.FileNotFoundException wan thrown. Additional exception information: could not file 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\17168\web.config

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not like having important things renamed without warning and so it does things like this.  A server rename is a pretty huge change and is something that really is best done immediately after the server is built and before any software other than the OS is installed.

The first thing to try would be to use the powershell [Rename-SPServer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607556.aspx) command to try to tell SharePoint about that change.  If that doesn't work then you may have to either rename it back to the old name (which might work) or completely uninstall and reinstall SharePoint.

Comment: I renamed it back! but when I run SharePoint Product Configuration Wizard it gives me the above Error!

Comment: At this point, you might need to try the Rename-SPServer command and give it a new name, then rename the server itself (the powershell command just tells SharePoint about the change).  Again, this *may* work.  You might have to completely uninstall/reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the SharePoint Server need some steps to be executed to ensure your SharePoint works error-free. SharePoint contains many references to the name of your machine throughout it’s database, and all of these must be changed as well. There is a PowerShell cmdlet called Rename-SPServer to make most of these changes.

I will recommend you reading this article and following the steps carefully:
http://www.bluesphereinc.com/blog/renaming-a-sharepoint-20102013-server/